# Passing parameters in link_to tag - rails 3 throwing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, format, parameter-passing, link-to

In my Rails application, I have a link_to field with the parameters, but it is not going to the action specified. Is there anything wrong with the format of link_to given below.

```
<%=link_to "Add sub question", :q_id => 13, :action => :question_types, :remote => true %>
```

I am getting no method error.

Actually, the method is there inside the `questions_controller`. The above line is in '`questions/new.html.erb`' file

Thanks for any help :)-

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error that you get. Generally you should use `link_to` as: `link_to link_text, link_url, any_other_options`, I imagine that is what is causing your problem. What it the path you want the link to lead to?

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify the controller

```
<%= link_to "Add sub question", :q_id => 13, :action => "question_types", :controller => "questions", :remote => true %>
```

Just make sure that you created the correct route

Comment: As this view corresponds to questions itself, I don't think that it is necessary to specify the :controller parameter.